# Delete matrix blocks based on their content

Tags: matrix

Is it possible to pragmatically delete a matrix block based on its content? I have a channel called "Artist", which has a matrix field with concerts. It'll be about 5-600 concerts in total every year, so it's a bit of a hassle to manually remove old concerts. Every block has a field with the concert date. Is it possible to remove matrix blocks based on that date?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you feel you need to delete the old content? Can't you just show events with relevant dates?

Comment: Instead of a matrix of concerts, you might have a channel of concerts, which could have an expiration date like other events.

Comment: @SteveRowling It will end up being a mess on the backend with 600 concerts in a year. It'll be near impossible to find anything after only a short while.

Comment: @MarionNewlevant The reason I can't have concerts as channels is because I'm using the free version, which only has one channel section. And it would still be a big mess with 600+ entries.